# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory – os.walk

Tags: python, file, os.walk, ioerror

I'm trying to run the following script which simply reads and image and saves it again:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

rootdir = '/home/user/Desktop/sample'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        im = Image.open(file)
        im.save(file)
```

I however get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    im = Image.open(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2258, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.jpg'
```

So, what I'm trying to do is simply read the file `1.jpg` and save it again, provided that `1.jpg` is located in the directory.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need to provide a fully qualified path, because `file` holds only the tail, not the entire path.

You can use `os.path.join` to join the `root` to the tail:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        im = Image.open(path)
        im.save(path)
```